# Storing an user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
      $('.bg').append('<input type="text" name="name">');

      $('<input type="text" name="name">').appendTo('.bg > div:eq(0)').on('keyup', function(){
      var link = $(this).val();           
    });
```

and I want to make variable "link" to appear in the input box every time the user enters the page. I think it should use local storing methods, but how do I do it?

I also tried using this

```
 var set = localStorage.setItem(link);
       var retrieved = localStorage.getItem(set);
        $('.bg').append($('<input>').prop('type', 'text').val(retrieved));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an identifier, then you can query the stored item by it's name:

```
// Storing an item
localStorage.setItem('link', link);
// Getting an item
var link = localStorage.getItem('link');
// Removing an item
localStorage.removeItem('link');
```

[Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) instead of localStorage that is not fully supported by the browsers.